# Running DBCC commands from Mybatis / Ibatis

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, ibatis, mybatis

I am trying to call a Sql Server DBCC command from mybatis and am getting back a list of the result names but not the values.

```
@select("dbcc useroptions")
List dbccUserOptions();
```

Returns only a list of the option names. Any ideas how to get the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I discovered this works:

```
@select("dbcc useroptions")
List<Map> dbccUserOptions();
```

It turns out that Mybatis is inspecting the return type and if it is a list of scalars it will only return the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Select("dbcc useroptions")
@MapKey("Set Option")
Map<String, String> dbccUserOptions();
```

Comment: This did not work for me, it complained about not finding a setter for Option and when I removed that line it complained that there were multiple results but the method is expecting one. Switching to List<Map> did the trick. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hummm... The driver for SQL Server must recognize the column name with different way. We need see this name for putting in the `@MapKey`